# mostrar datos de todos los mes x año, aunque esten vacios

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una consulta sql, la cual me trae el listado de tareas realizadas por mes en un año determinado. Esta consulta se hace a dos tablas, una de tareas, con fecha y labor realizada, y otra tabla, en donde estan los meses en numero y descripcion de mes (Ej. 2 - Febrero).

```
SELECT t2.mes_nombre, COUNT(*) AS 'cantidad_tareas'
FROM tareas t1
LEFT JOIN meses t2
   ON MONTH(t1.Fecha_emision) = t2.mes
WHERE YEAR(t1.Fecha_emision) = 2020 -- año a consultar
GROUP BY MONTH(Fecha_emision)
```

El asunto es que ahora me pidieron que realizara una consulta, la cual traiga todos los meses del año, para un determinado año, y la cantidad de tareas realizadas, independiente de si hay tareas hechas o no por mes,y no logro realizarlo. Ej: Tareas para el año 2019:

```
| mes        | cantidad_tareas |
|------------|-----------------|
| Enero      | 0               |
| Febrero    | 10              |
| Marzo      | 25              |
| Abril      | 0               |
| Mayo       | 7               |
| Junio      | 11              |
| Julio      | 0               |
| Agosto     | 19              |
| Septiembre | 35              |
| Octubre    | 0               |
| Noviembre  | 41              |
| Dicmebre   | 35              |
```

Si me pudiesen orientar con esta consulta, se los agradeceria mucho, y asi aprender mas para futuros casos.

Comment: tenes que crear una tabla calendario y usarla para joinear... busca en el sitio sobre eso

Answer (score 0):

Si la tabla `meses` tiene los 12 meses del año, entonces usa un `RIGHT JOIN`:

```
SELECT t2.mes_nombre, COUNT(*) AS 'cantidad_tareas'
FROM tareas t1
RIGHT JOIN meses t2
   ON MONTH(t1.Fecha_emision) = t2.mes
WHERE YEAR(t1.Fecha_emision) = 2020 -- año a consultar
GROUP BY t2.mes
```